# What evidence does magnesium, zinc & melatonin help you sleep?

Tags: effectiveness, magnesium, sleep-aids, melatonin, zinc

So I have read doctors/nurse practitioner have prescribed Zinc, Magnesium and Melatonin for sleep problems.

Is there evidence of this and where?

Comment: http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/marek-doyle/help-me-sleep-magnesium-secret-to-sleep-problems_b_3311795.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnesium, zinc and melatonin help to manage and control the sleep problems. These three natural components have their own mechanisms in managing the sleep disorders.
Firstly, talking about Melatonin:

> Disturbances in the rhythm and amplitude of melatonin secretion may account for symptomatic disturbances to sleep and mood. Melatonin treatment not only improved total sleep time, but also reduced depressive symptoms,indicating a relationship between sleep disturbance and symptoms of depression. The pineal hormone melatonin (N-acetyl-5-methoxytryptamine) acts as a neuroendocrine transducer of the light–dark cycle. It plays an important role in regulating human circadian rhythms and may have sleep-inducing effects in humans. Melatonin production declines with age and is lower in middle-aged and elderly adults with insomnia than in good sleepers.[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21226679)

Zinc exhibits an antidepressant-like
activity, related to its action as an antagonist of
the glutamate/N-methyl-D-aspartate receptor.

In the case of sleep, Magnesium is  the primary ingredient in muscle relaxation, has a neuroprotective effect that is absolutely crucial to each and every stage of sleep, assists in slowing metabolic processes and lowering brain temperature as your body attempts to repair daily damage during sleep cycles, and helps regulate key hormones responsible for not only helping you fall asleep, but keeping you asleep.

A [Study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21226679) published in the Journal of American Geriatrics Society was able to investigate the benefits of the combination of zinc, melatonin and magnesium in the treatment of insomnia in elderly people. The results of the study revealed that the combination of natural supplements provided the following outcomes:

• It increased the total sleep time of the participants

• There was a reduction in hangover on waking up

• The quality of the sleep was improved

• It also improved the alertness and the behavior in the morning after taking the supplements

• Going to sleep was made easier

Sources :

https://www.adamkempfitness.com/melatoninzinc/

http://www.hollywoodhomestead.com/magnesium-over-melatonin-to-induce-sleep/

http://www.ancient-minerals.com/blog-post/magnesium-sleep/

Comment: So did it help them fall asleep?  It appears to just help quality of sleep and duration of sleep, but I'm no expert on this.