# Is there evidence of sleep medication permanently damaging your ability to sleep?

Tags: irreversible-damage

Most sleep medications have recommendations for short-term use, yet sometimes they are prescribed over months to years.

According to [this](https://www.everydayhealth.com/news/risks-taking-sleeping-pills/) source:

> You can have problems when you use them longer than 7 to 10 days.

Is there evidence for permanent alteration or damage to the brain with long-term use?  For example, can it cause narcolepsy or extreme chronic insomnia?  I could see the Z or benzos maybe cause permanent brain damage after an overdose.  But what about chronic use at standard dosing?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. We require some evidence demonstrating independent research of the problem domain has been conducted, and that you will also understand the answer. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: @LangLangC this question seems quite similar to this question I asked.  https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10764/what-evidence-does-magnesium-zinc-melatonin-help-you-sleep  I would put a specific medication, but was afraid it may be limiting.

Comment: @LangLangC my research has shown virtually no experiments of this length because most studies are short term.  Sleep medications are not advised to be taken long term and if you compound the withdrawal it would literally last months.

Comment: "Limiting": sometimes small is beautiful. Are you talking valerian, lemon balm, barbiturates, alcohol, hops, cannabis, passionflower, benzodiazepams, Z-meds, Chloral hydrate…?  Brains have plasticity, neurons and synapses are adaptive. How they react and change depends.

Comment: @LangLangC I'm currently not taking any of those.  This is supposed to be a general question.  Natural solutions are not what I would call sleep remedies.  I would think most people would take Z-meds or benzodiaepems but again I'm not sure.

Comment: Good. Talking≠taking. If you focus your [edit] on benzos and Zs, adding your research about their effects it seems on a good way.

Comment: @LangLangC I would like to mention there is one type of medication that is commonly prescribed for sleep issues that you forget to mention.  Antipsychotics